# How can I tell if a tuple is empty in c++

Tags: c++, stl, std

I want to know how I can identify if my tuple is empty?
Note that I use std::tuble in conjunction with std::map as below:

```
typedef std::tuple<SDESType,INT32,std::string> SDesItem;
typedef std::map<SDESType,SDesItem> SDesItemMap;
```

Now I want to check if the second value of `SDesItemMap`, that is a tuple, is empty or not?

```
if(SDesItems[SDESType] != NULL) // this is error
```

Comment: A tuple cannot be empty (unless it is `tuple<>`, in which case it is always empty.)

Comment: What do you mean by `is empty` ? A `std::tuple` as a fixed size, in your case 3 elements, so it won't ever be empty.

Comment: what do you mean by empty? I think that a tuple must always contain values, so the only thing you can do, is asking your SDESType, INT32, std::string whether they are "empty".

Comment: you can check if `SDesItems` has an item at the key `SDESType` but your tuple always has 3 elements.

Comment: oh yes , i forgot it , tuple can not be empty.is there any equivelant type?
for clarify , i mean it has value or not?

Comment: What do you mean with "equivalent type"?

Comment: a data type like tuple?

Comment: Tuple is exactly equivalent with itself. There would be no point to having another equivalent type. Why would you want one?

Comment: If there was, one would be redundant

Comment: You could specify pointer-types in your tuple, like typedef std::tuple<SDESType*,INT32*,std::string*> SDesItem; and you can pass NULL for empty values - but that is quite ugly.

Comment: why not use a `class` or `struct` instead of a `tuple`?

Comment: risingDarkness : yes you right, i must use struct and create my owm siple tuple item

Comment: [Boost Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) is a type that has "possibly no value" semantics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::tuple` acts like three values tied together. It has no predefined "empty" or "zero" state, other than empty states of each of its members. Empty value is always contextual, and in general means a value lying outside the domain of the regular type's values.

For example, a natural number can only be 0 (or 1, depending on your definition) upward. Thus, using an `int` gives you a convenient way to represent a value that's outside of the domain, and should be treated irregularly.

To represent that cleanly in your example, use `optional<tuple<...>>` as a map value (if you want to specifically state "there's an **empty value** at a given key"). This type states that the possible values of the type you get by instantiating the `optional` template are now all of the values of the original type,  *and* a special, *nothing* (*/empty/none*) value.

You can also state that *parts* of the tuple can be empty (nothing), like

```
tuple <
    std::string,   // empty string ("") can be treated as "empty state"
    optional<int>, // if you don't want to treat 0 (or -1) as "empty"
>
```

`optional<>` is not a part of `std::` yet, so you have to write your own implementation or use [the Boost one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). Another way would be using `value_ptr` (Boost again), but here it wouldn't probably give you any benefits.